# I'm Asking An Easy One

Tags: riddle, word, pattern, rhyme

> I was a dreamer who dreamed to the end
>   A maker of song so that you had a friend
>   I went on singing, standing by soon and late
>   In the icy cold waters of the northernmost state.
>   I am a man  from a popular game.
>   I am a beast that a beauty could tame.
>   I was nicknamed a bone at the top of my fame.
>   A hillock in Georgia reveals my name.

Feel free to have a shot at it, particularly if you're a 60s and 70s buff.

Comment: As to the last line, I'm thinking (rot13ed for spoilers) fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu rvgure "xvat" be "ybpxvat", orpnhfr gurl'er va gur jbeqf "uvyybpx va Trbetvn".

Comment: @Deusovi rot26 for double the security: yup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer might be

> King

---

### Explanation:

I was a dreamer who dreamed to the end

> Martin Luther **King** with "I have a dream"

A maker of song so that you had a friend

> Carole **King**: "You've Got A Friend"

I went on singing, standing by soon and late

> Song "Stand by me" by singer-songwriter Ben E. **King**
>  or Movie "Stand by me" based on novel by Stephen **King**

In the icy cold waters of the northernmost state.

> Alaskan **King** crab

I am a man from a popular game.

> The **king** in the game of chess

I am a beast that a beauty could tame.

> **King** Kong with closing quote "It was beauty killed the beast" (courtesy of Hugh Meyers)

I was nicknamed a bone at the top of my fame.

> Elvis "the pelvis" Presley, the **King** of Rock and Roll, (courtesy of Hugh Meyers)

A hillock in Georgia reveals my name.

> hilloc **K in G** eorgia (found by @Deusovi)

Comment: You didn't get the beauty/beast one? That was the first one that jumped out at me

Comment: The two missing ones (rot13) are: Xvat Xbat. Va obgu gur bevtvany naq gur zbfg erprag erznxr "Vg jnf ornhgl xvyyrq gur ornfg" jnf n ovt pybfvat dhbgr. The final one was maybe too obscure. There was an American folk singer who had a few hits in the 50s and 60s. He was nicknamed both Gur Xvat naq Ryivf "gur cryivf" Cerfyrl.

Comment: Also, for the record, I was thinking of your first answer for the "popular game" clue because the pieces are called "men". Ideally, I would have made the title a cute punning reference to the solution but couldn't quite manage it. It's supposed to be kind of "V nz, nf xvat, na rnfl bar." Ah, well.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is :

> Jarvis Jerrell Jones. Who is a Linebacker for Pittsburgh Steelers of the National Football League

I am a man from a popular game.

> Football.

I am a beast that a beauty could tame.

> Position:    Linebacker. A beast in this defense.Jack Lambert Award winner in 2012.

I was nicknamed a bone at the top of my fame.

> Jones is sometimes referred to as "Dawg Bones" Jones.

A hillock in Georgia reveals my name.

> an American football linebacker for the Pittsburgh Steelers of the National Football League (NFL).Jones was born in Columbus, Georgia and grew up in Lumpkin and Richland, Georgia. He attended Carver High School in Columbus, Georgia, where he led his high school football team to a state title in 2007, and was rated as a four-star recruit by Rivals.com.In addition to playing football, he was also an all-state basketball player.He was ranked the 59th best high school prospect by ESPN.

Comment: Please always add spoilers in your answer... :)

Comment: @manshu New to this community. Lesson learnt.

Comment: I am impressed by your research. The actual answer was intended to be much closer to hand. I have improved the riddle (I hope) to make it less broad and more doable.

Comment: @manshu Yes. I meant that I didn't intend to make readers do so much research.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> John Lennon

Because:

> Dreamer and song maker are obvious. 
>  "with a little help from my friends"
>  Spent a lot of time in Alaska. 
>  Popular game can reference music industry. 
>  Beast references Beatles and the beauty is yoko. 
>  Georgia guidestones?